# Trying to achive floating input simiar to what we see on the Gmail login

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the floating input, similar to what we have on the gmail login. And i did go through few other resourse, but could not achieve it. Also, am trying the same with the textarea tag for the collecting the address. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

[image]

Here is my code. Its working to an extent, but when the content on the placeholder is entered, then it overlaps with the lable.

```css
/* fonts  */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@400;500&display=swap");

/* fonts  */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
}

section {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.form {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #666;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.customerName,
.contactNumber {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #04aa6d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  color: #666;
  transition: 0.3s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.customerName:focus + .placeholder,
.contactNumber:focus + .placeholder {
  top: -10px;
  color: #04aa6d;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.9) translateY(-0%) translateX(-10px);
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/css/styles.css" />
    <title>Test Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h2 class="title">Test Form</h2>
    </header>
    <main>
      <!-- customer Details start -->
      <section>
        <h5>Customer Details</h5>
        <form class="form">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="input customerName" />
            <label class="placeholder">Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" class="contactNumber" />
            <label class="placeholder">Mobile</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <label class="placeholder">Address</label>
            <textarea
              class="contactNumber"
              rows="4"
              cols="32"
            >
              Enter Address here...
            </textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
      <!-- customer Details end -->
    </main>
    <script src="assests/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you need a `valid` pseudo-class of some kind

Comment: I'm too lazy to fit it with your code, but you can check this [link](https://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/), pretty sure can apply to textarea too.

Answer (score 0):

This should work
You've tried adding the

```
:not
```

pseudo selector but the line you've added doesn't work because you need to specify more on

```
:not(:focus)
```

on the targeted element.
Here's how the full code looks like.

```css
/* CSS styles */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@400;500&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.form {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #666;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1{
  margin: 0;
}
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.customerName,
.contactNumber{
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #04aa6d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 18px;
  background:none;
}
.placeholder{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.3s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.input:focus + .placeholder{
  top: -10px;
  color: #04aa6d;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
}
.input:not(:placeholder-shown).input:not(:focus)+ .placeholder{
  top:-12px;
  left: 12px;
  color: #04aa6d;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transform: scale(0.9) translateY(-0%) translateX(-10px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      <h2 class="title">Test Form</h2>
    </header>
  <main>
      <!-- customer Details start -->
      <section>
        <h5>Customer Details</h5>
             <form action="" class="form">
               
               <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="text" class="input customerName" placeholder=" ">
                     <label for="" class="placeholder">Name</label>
                 </div>
               
                 <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="password" class="input contactNumber" placeholder=" ">
                    <label for="" class="placeholder">Password</label>
                </div>
               
             <div class="input-group">
            <label class="placeholder">Address</label>
            <textarea
              class="contactNumber"
              rows="4"
              cols="32"
            >
              Enter Address here...
            </textarea>
          </div>
             </form>
              </section>
      <!-- customer Details end -->
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it Helps !!.